# Error al subir imagenes en laravel a base de datos

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy intentando subir una imagen a la base de datos desde un formulario

Esta es mi vista

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/saveAbsence'), ['id' => 'absenceForm'], ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) }}
{{Form::file('cover_image')}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

Este es mi controlador

```
public function storage(imageRequest $request){
       $image = $request->file('cover_image');
       $file = $image->store('img');

       $request->merge(['image'=> $file]);
       $cover = product::create($request->all());
}
```

Pero obtengo este error

```
"message": "Call to a member function store() on null"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que la variable $cover obtiene un arreglo con varios archivos que se pueden haber subido, por lo que debes cambiar

```
$cover = product::create($request->all());
```

por

```
$cover = product::create($request->first());
```

lo cual sí devuelve un solo objeto, y si quieres recorrer el arreglo completo, debes hacer un ciclo desde 0 a el length del arreglo.

Saludos!